# What is wrong with my syntax in Objective-C when defining a method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, implementation

```
-(NSMutableArray *) forwardInterfaceList: (networkInterface *) i;
```

I get the error "Expected ')' before 'networkInterface'"

Whole implementation section here:

```
@interface device : NSObject{

    NSString *hostname;
    NSMutableArray *intList;
}

-(NSMutableArray *) forwardInterfaceList: (networkInterface *) i;
-(NSMutableArray *) intList;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be using capitals for your Class names...
but aside from that you probably don't have the name in scope, which would by fixed with importing its declaration or doing a forward declaration...

```
@class NetworkInterface;
```

Comment: It was being imported, but both of my classes had a property that was for the other. Doing that forward declaration in both worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remember to `import` the header where `networkInterface` has been declared.

**E.g.**

```
#import "networkInterface.h"
```

*at the top of you file.*

Comment: You are correct. So I made sure that it was being imported, and it is. But there is an error over there on that file.

Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'device'

Comment: It was effectively because it wasn't being imported properly. Thanks!